# Showing magento new product like standard category

Tags: magento

In magento 1.4 it has default page showing new products but how can I show all these products in one page like ordinary category showing all items underneath.. My current setup is showing 8 new products in homepage and a link to show all new products.

Answer (score 0):

To change the number of new products on the homepage, you should be able to edit the value in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php

Change
`const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 5;`
to whatever value you'd like - or 999 to show all new.

Comment: I was able to do that Emily, What I want is a separate page if user click on more new products after the 5 products shown on magento homepage, and I want to jump from homepage to another page showing all new products if more link is clicked.